# calculate the time that a calculation needs and subtract computer time error iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am programming a calculator for iPad and I am trying to find a way to count the time a calculation needs to execute.

At the moment I am trying a simple calculation : `NSLog(@"power is : %g", pow(number,2));`

**I want to seed 3000 numbers to this calculation and store the needed times into an array .

Should I use a NSTimer to find this time?**

The computer makes an error counting time . I would like to subtract this error from the results so as to get more precise values.

I used CADisplayLink because I can start and stop it setting paused to false and true and not a NSTimer because I would have to initiate a NStiemr object every time and it would be time and memory consuming.

So far I have written the following code but it does not work.

Thank you in advance

```
-(void)howMuchTimeForASquared
{
    xronoi=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sumTime=0;
    CADisplayLink *gameTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self
                                            [gameTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                                                            forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    if (xronos>3000) {
        NSLog(@"xronoi count %d",xronoi.count);
        gameTimer.invalidate;
    }
}

-(void) updateDisplay:(CADisplayLink*)sender
{
    srandom( time( NULL ) );
    int randomNumber=((random())%3000);
    xronos++;
    [self updateModelWithTime:sender.timestamp];
}

-(void) updateModelWithTime:(CFTimeInterval) timestamp{
    if (lastTime == 0.0) {
        lastTime = timestamp;
    } else {
        timeDelta = timestamp - lastTime;
        sumTime=sumTime+timeDelta;
        [xronoi addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeDelta]];
        lastTime = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ichanged the code as follows . Now i think that the values are calculated correctly . Could you check please just to verify? However the issue with the computer time error remains. Could you guide me please on how i can eliminate this error in order to get more precise results? Thank you in advance.

Comment: -(void)howMuchTimeForASquared
    {
    xronoi=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    xronos=0;
    sumTime=0;
    gameTimer = [CADisplayLink 
    displayLinkWithTarget:selfselector:@selector(updateDisplay:)];                                                     
    [gameTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
    forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }

Comment: -(void) updateDisplay:(CADisplayLink*)sender
    {
    if (xronos>3000) {
    NSLog(@"xronoi count %d",xronoi.count);
    gameTimer.invalidate;
    }else
    {
    srandom( time( NULL ) );
    int randomNumber=((random())%3000);
    xronos++;
    NSLog(@"updated testtetragwno %g",pow(randomNumber, 2));
    [self updateModelWithTime:sender.timestamp];
    }
    }

Comment: -(void) updateModelWithTime:(CFTimeInterval) timestamp{
    if (lastTime == 0.0)
    {
    lastTime = timestamp;
    }
    else
    {
    timeDelta = timestamp - lastTime;
    NSLog(@"hei3 xronos %d timedelta %g ",xronos,timeDelta);
    [xronoi addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeDelta]];
    lastTime = timestamp;
    }
    }